# Поиск кратчайшего пути в SQL от одной вершины до всех

Tags: sql, алгоритм, postgresql

Пишу алгоритм нахождения кратчайшего пути(С минимальным весом) от вершины S до всех остальных, понимаю, в чём ошибка : минимальный путь до одной вершины не является минимальным для другой, это и сбивает алгоритм как можно исправить код ?
Код:

```
-- Код для поиска всех кратчайших путей от вершины S
with recursive temp AS
                   (select id,
                           array [id] as path,
                           0          as price,
                           false      as cycle
                    from "DbWorkHierarchy"
                    where id = 'S'
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT "DbWorkHierarchy".id,
                           temp.path || "DbWorkHierarchy".id      as path,
                           temp.price + "DbWorkHierarchy".weight  as price,
                           "DbWorkHierarchy".id = any (temp.path) as cycle
                from "DbWorkHierarchy"
                         JOIN temp on (temp.id = "DbWorkHierarchy".par_id) AND NOT cycle)

select id as edge, path as nodes, price as cost
from temp
where id
    -- Выбор всех вершин, до которых дошел
    in (SELECT id as edge from temp group by id)
  --выбор самой малой цены, за которую дошел до вершин
  and price in (
    SELECT min(price) as cost
    from temp
    group by id)
;
```

Таблица:
[image: DbWorkHierarchy]

Я пробовал перебрать все вершины в цикле:

```
DO
$do$
    DECLARE
        x varchar;
        /*array1 varchar[]:=  array['S','U','X','V','Y'];*/
    BEGIN


    foreach x in array ['S','U','X','V','Y']
        LOOP
            with recursive temp AS
                               (select id,
                                       array [id] as path,
                                       0          as price,
                                       false      as cycle
                                from "DbWorkHierarchy"
                                where id = 'S'
                                UNION ALL
                                SELECT "DbWorkHierarchy".id,
                                       temp.path || "DbWorkHierarchy".id      as path,
                                       temp.price + "DbWorkHierarchy".weight  as price,
                                       "DbWorkHierarchy".id = any (temp.path) as cycle

                                from "DbWorkHierarchy"
                                         JOIN temp on (temp.id = "DbWorkHierarchy".par_id
                                                          ) AND NOT cycle)
            SELECT id as edge, path as nodes, price as cost
            from temp
            where id = x
              and price in (select min(price) from temp where id = x);
        END LOOP;
END;
$do$;
```

Но получаю ошибку :[42601] ОШИБКА: ошибка синтаксиса (примерное положение: "["

Примечание: Граф ориентирован, направление от par_id к id

UPD код для создания и заполнения таблицы :

```
create  table DbWorkHierarchy (
   id varchar,
   par_id varchar,
   weight integer

);

insert into DbWorkHierarchy (id, par_id, weight) VALUES  ('X', 'S',5)
                                                       ,('U', 'S',3),
                                                        ('Y','V',2),
                                                        ('X','U',2)
                                                        ,('Y','X',6),
                                                        ('S','Y',3),
                                                        ('V','Y',7),
                                                        ('U','X',1),
                                                        ('V','U',9),
                                                        ('V','X',4),

                                                        ('T','X',4),
                                                        ('V','T',2);
```

UPD:
SQL Fiddle URL : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ba262/2

Comment: [Алгоритм Дейкстры](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B)

Comment: Выложите пример данных - CREATE TABLE исходной таблицы, INSERT INTO с тест-данными, эталонный ответ для показанных данных.

Comment: В принципе - обычная рекурсия. Критерий рекурсивного отбора - присоединяемая вершина отсутствует в пути. А затем нумерация по суммарной цене (или ранг - в зависимости от точной формулировки задачи) в партиции по конечной вершине и отбор первой.

Comment: Akina, что вы имеете ввиду под словом партиции ?-Наследованные таблицы ?Или вы про оконные функции и Partition By? Можете объяснить подробнее

Comment: Разместите пример структуры и данных на http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: Anatoly, разместил ссылка : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ba262/2